# How to send pipeline Endtime as an alert using Email by SendGrid plugin in Data Fusion (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sendgrid, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am using a pipeline in Data Fusion, which reads data from CSV files in Cloud Storage, transforms it using wrangler and inserts the data in a table in Big Query. I want to send an alert after the pipeline has completed its run using Email by Sendgrid plugin. I tried using ${logicalStartTime} in macro functions, but it states the Start time when the pipeline has run. How do I send the end time of the pipeline run using Email By Sendgrid plugin?

Answer (score 0):

a suggestion is to put a BQ Execute at the end of the pipeline (very last step) with a query like this:
`select current_timestamp() as logicalEndTime;`
After which setting the "Row as Arguments" flag in the BQ Execute step to "True", would set logicalEndTime as a variable that future macros can use.

Comment: Hi Sanjana, Thanks for the help. I tried using this, but getting an error - `Argument {argument_name} is not defined`. Like you suggested, I added BQ Execute at the end and toggled the Row as Arguments to True, but I am not able to use this macro in Sendgrid email plugin.